# How to Inject Dependencies into a Servlet Filter with Spring Boot Filter Registration Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlet-filters

I have a Servlet Filter within my Spring Boot (2.0.1) application that I'm registering with `FilterRegistrationBean` which I need it to be executed first (order of one) along the filter chain. The application is deployed to **JBoss 7.2**. This filter also has a dependency that is injected with `@Autowired` (see below):

```
package my.pkg.com
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"my.pkg.com"})
public class MyApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public satic void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(1)
  public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> contextFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    contextFilter.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    contextFilter.addUrlPattern("/api/*");
    return contextFilter;
  }
}


package my.pkg.com.filter

public class MyFilter extends Filter {

  @Autowired
  private MyService mySrv;


  @Override

  public void doFilter(…) {

    mySrv.doSomething(); // mySrv is null
  }
}
```

The problem is when the application is deployed and ran, when the Servlet request gets to `MyFilter.doFilter()`, `mySrv` is null which means `MyFilter` was never scanned for dependency injections.

I can verify through debugging `MyService` which is a `@Repository` in `my.package.com.repository` package does get initialized. It just never gets injected into `MyFilter`.

I can create a constructor for `MyFilter` to take `MyService`, then `@Autowired` `MyService` into `MyApp` and during filter registration, I can pass it to this constructor, which resolves the issue.

However, I want to know if there is anything I'm doing wrong that this dependency doesn't get injected into `MyFilter` with using the setup above alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create an object by yourself, using `new`, and this object is not returned by a `@Bean`-annotated method, then it's not a Spring bean, and Spring will thus not inject anything in it.

You can just add an @Bean-annotated method returning `new MyFilter()`, and call that method from `myFilter()` to get the bean, or add a `MyFilter` as argument to `myFilter()`.

Example:

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> contextFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    contextFilter.setFilter(theActualFilter());
    contextFilter.addUrlPattern("/api/*");
    return contextFilter;
}

@Bean 
public MyFilter theActualFilter() {
    return new MyFilter(); // now this is a Spring bean
}
```

or

```
@Bean
@Order(1)
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter(MyFilter theActualFilter) {
    FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> contextFilter = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    contextFilter.setFilter(theActualFilter);
    contextFilter.addUrlPattern("/api/*");
    return contextFilter;
}

@Bean 
public MyFilter theActualFilter() {
    return new MyFilter(); // now this is a Spring bean
}
```

Comment: That seems to work in JBoss 7.2. My assumption was that `FilterRegistrationBean` would make the actual `Filter` object to be managed by Spring container. Does it only add it to the Servlet container and not application context? What's happening here exactly?

Comment: It registers the filter you provide as a servlet filter, without caring f it's a bean or not. Not all filters need to be Spring beans. If one needs to be a bean, you need to make it a bean.

Comment: I see. So it simply adds it to the servlet context. Thanks. **Do you know by any chance why this code doesn't work with Spring Boot Tomcat**? It seems like the Filter class doesn't even get called which I presume means the filter doesn't get added to the chain for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, add `@Component` annotation on your filter class and it will make `@Autowired` annotation working inside as Spring dependency injection will process your filter class and inject the service bean.

Comment: Spring doesn't scan the Servlet `Filter` class for some reason by registering that filter with `FilterRegisrationBean`.